# Running a program from the USB when it's plugged in

Tags: windows

I have 2 files in my usb stick:

file 1: "Autorun.inf"

```
[autorun]
open=ConsoleApplication1.exe
Label=(memory stick hehehe)
```

file 2: "ConsoleApplication1.exe"

when i plug in my usb stick it changes the label name to "memory stick hehehe" but it doesnt run the .exe? whats the problem, im using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected. Mass storage autorun was extensively used to spread malware in Windows XP times. It was disabled in Windows 7, as far as I remember.